# How do I find and delete datatips throughout my solution in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, performance, debugging, expression-evaluation, datatip

I noticed that lots of <s>expression evaluation popups</s> **datatips** severely slow down going in and out of debugging, so I'd like to delete most of them (for that I need to find them first, is there a button for that?) or if it's not an option, delete all of them at once.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're asking about the immediate window, you have to right click in it and click `Clear`.

These are called "DataTips" and you can find options to manipulate them in the `Debug` menu.

Go to `Menu > Debug` and there you will find `Clear All DataTips`, `Export DataTips`, `Import DataTips` etc... When you're actively debugging you can find an extra option to clear DataTips per file.

Hope this helps!

Comment: In debug mode, when you go to Break, hover above an expression and press pin button to pin it to a place in code, it stays there and tries to evaluate that expression every time you go in and out of debug mode.

Comment: You can unpin these. I find it helpful to have these expressions added into the Watch. I don't think there is a way to prevent re-evaluation in this case.

Comment: To unpin them I must find them first. That's what this question is about.

Comment: Ah, these are called DataTips :-)
So go to top the menu Debug -> Clear All DataTips. This will unpin them all. Sorry i really didn't understand what you asked :-) 
You can also clear them in specific file, there will be option in the Debug menu. Have fun!